# run javascript code after python if statement

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to achieve the following. In my python code I have a if statement that checks for the response from a API server. if the response is 201 I want to run a code snippet inn javascript. The response is determined after a form is submitted in html.

I have then declared a variable globally and that variable is set to false. After the response is 201 i set this variable to true. If this variable is true i want to run a code snippet.

```
        submit = False
        if response == 201:
            submit = True
            response_page = redirect("next_url")
            # redirect to next step
            return response_page
```

Inn my javascript code I check for the variable like so:

```
    function setData(){
        if('{{submit}}'=="True"){
            #Run code
        }
    }
```

The setData() function is run when the form is submitted. But it doesn’t work because the function does not wait for the server response. Any one have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that u don't want to fetch it through js.
maybe do setInterval() and clearInterval()

```
let setData;
if (!setData) {
setData = setInterval(function setData(){
    if('{{submit}}'=="True"){
        #Run code
        clearInterval(setData);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

I'm pretty new hope it helps.